# Setting a fixed height to a block breaks the 100% width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

The problem is when I try to set `height: 20px` to all rows this breaks the natural `width: 100%` from a block element. This bug only occurs on IE7 (tested on FF, Chrome and IE8).

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
   This must be adjusted to content
    <div class="row">row 1</div>
    <div class="row">row 2</div>
    <div class="row">row 3</div>
    <div class="row">row #</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.row {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin-top: 2px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/97fax/3/

**Notes**

- I'm testing on IE8 with compatability mode for IE7
- Setting a fixed width to container and set `width: 100%` for rows is not an option.
  ​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to find a fellow country man :)

Just tested with **"line-height: 20px;"** instead of **"height: 20px;"** and worked just fine on:

1. IE 7
2. IE 8
3. FF3+
4. Safari
5. Chrome
6. Opera

Doc-Type used for this test was "strict".

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer you're looking for (a table, ugh), but here goes...

```
<div id="container">
    <table><tbody><tr><td>
        This must be adjusted to content
        <div class="row">row 1</div>
        <div class="row">row 2</div>
        <div class="row">row 3</div>
        <div class="row">row #</div>
    </td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

I spent 1/2 an hour trying various combinations of [`hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) and `position: relative` and `inline`/`inline-block` etc, but a table was all I could get working I'm afraid :-(